# firestore not updating results

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with firestore in NodeJS, and wrote the function below, this function receives the results array as a parameter, which contains the firestore doc id that needs to be updated.

So, for each document, i am calling the set method to add the fileName field to this document. But for some reason, the result only updated when i have a single id in this results array.

Can someone help me?

```
async function update(results, fileName) {
    
        results.forEach(data => {
    
          let id = firestore.collection('My_collection').doc(data.DOC_ID)
    
          id.set(
            { filename: fileName}, {merge:true}
          )
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding a promise to your code.

```
async function update(results, fileName) {
    
        results.forEach(data => {
    
          let id = firestore.collection('My_collection').doc(data.DOC_ID)
    
          await id.set({ filename: fileName}, {merge:true})
        })
    }
```

Like shown in the documentation[1]

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#add_data